# How to cast the fraction into 2 decimal point?

Tags: sql

I want calculate percentage. The given below query is calculating the percentage.
SQL :

```
select TeamName, Count1,Count0,
(count1*100.0)/nullif(Max(Count1) over(),0) Percentage1,
(count0*100.0)/nullif(max(Count1) over(),0) Percentage2
from tbl_Percentage
```

It showing the result in grid view as given below:

```
TeamName   Count1   Count0    Percentage1      Percentage0
--------   -----    ------    -----------      -----------
Team1        1        2        33.3333333%     66.66666666%
Team2        3        0        100.000000%     0.000000000%
Team3        1        1        33.3333333%     33.33333333%
```

I want to reduce the fraction into 3 decimal point. And shown like given below:

```
TeamName   Count1   Count0  Percentage1  Percentage0
--------   -----    ------  -----------  -----------
Team1        1        2        33.33%       66.66%
Team2        3        0        100.00%      0.00%
Team3        1        1        33.33%       33.33%
```

Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Comment: What is your database platform? Most platforms support [`round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) or similar functions.

Comment: You say round, but 66.66666666% -> 66.66%? Thats truncate, and can be done using CAST(value as decimal(4,2)).

Comment: @jarlh: Hi I am new in sql coding. Can you please help me to modify the above query?

Comment: Please tell us which DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : SQL

Comment: SQL is a language, not a dbms product. Perhaps you mean Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @Reshma The percentage you are getting is giving a wrong result ( and you can see it with team3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select TeamName, Count1,Count0,
Cast((count1*100.0)/nullif(Max(Count1) over(),0) as decimal(9,3)) Percentage1,
 Cast((count0*100.0)/nullif(max(Count1) over(),0),3)as decimal(9,3))  Percentage2
from tbl_Percentage
```